# public source of streaming IP addresses

Tags: data-request, api, real-time

I'd like to build a data pipeline, for demonstration purposes, that enriches a stream of data containing IP addresses with location, ISP, organization, etc... using [MaxMind's GeoIP2 Downloadable Databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/).

Does anyone know of a public source of streaming data that contains IP addresses? Perhaps something in the cybersecurity space (since this domain often deals with IP addresses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use torrents to collect the IP addresses of peers, although the coding is a bit tricky because of the protocol. I was looking into it as a hobby project, to use Python libraries. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4418157/2327328) for more details.

---

For fun, [Netflix Uses Pirate Sites to Determine What Shows to Buy](https://torrentfreak.com/netflix-uses-pirate-sites-to-determine-what-shows-to-buy-130914/)

Comment: Thanks @philshem. That's a great suggestion. I was able to get torrent peer IP's using this client: https://github.com/mpetazzoni/ttorrent

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it meets the criteria for "open data", but you can search [Shodan](https://www.shodan.io/explore) for public IP addresses of an assortment of streaming data, like webcams (for videos) media servers (for audio and video).

Comment: Thanks so much, @Anthony. That's certainly a very interesting site. 'Streaming', in this case, is a slightly ambiguous term. I'm looking for an API or websocket service that sends a 'stream' of messages that contain IP addresses (and other data). I was going to enrich that data with Nifi and make it searchable/queryable in Solr and Hive. The 'streaming' in Shodan seems to be video content rather than messages containing IP addresses.